# Do I have to worry about thread safety in flash?

Tags: flash, thread-safety

Is it true that in the flash/air player the actionscripts are all run in a single thread? Are all those event listeners invoked one by one and never overlap? If not, is there a way I can worry about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, in ActionScript a block of code is always single threaded. i.e. it always blocks the execution of others until finished. If I am not mistaken the only time the Flash runtime executes code in a separate thread is when it is making network calls.

In the AS event model, the events do not overlap; i.e. there is no way two event listeners will be called simultaneously. They will always be executed one after the other; and this holds even for events resulting from network calls.

You would have a hard time estimating the order of the events in the cases where you have many separate events however; because most of the event model is tightly integrated to the display list. In such cases it would be best to devise some kind of a queue system first.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to worry about it. ActionScript execution is single-threaded.

Answer (score 0):

Flash/Air working on single thread, except the code running in the background witch you do not have acces two. If you would like to set a priority to your event, you can do it in the [addEventListener](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#addEventListener%28%29) function of EventDispatcher.